# chmod/chown always writing updates even if not required

Tags: linux, posix, acl, chmod, chown

Whenever I do a "zfs diff" on certain zfs file systems, the output is cluttered by "modified" user files that get "changed" by running chmod over them (in a cron, to ensure some security aspects).

Question: is there an easy way that I missed to force (POSIX) permissions and ownership on file hierarchies without chmod/chown touching them when the permissions are already as I want them to be?

Comment: I mean...you could check the ownership and permissions first, and then only chown/chmod if necessary. Fairly simple in a high level language (python, or whatever the cool kids are using these days), probably a bit of a PITA in the shell but maybe possible using the `stat` command.

Comment: sure, I can always patch chmod/chown... but I'm quite sure I'm not the first one to solve this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like

```
find dir/ -type f -perm /0111 -exec chmod a-x {} +
```

instead of an unconditional `chmod` to remove the permissions. (all the `x` permissions here.)

Comment: Cool. Just what I thought: some as of yet undiscovered (by me) functionality hidden deep in some man page. :)

Answer (score 1):

The fact aside that *security by cron* sounds like a bad idea the simple answer is "**No**".  Neither `chmod` nor `chown` have a flag to do a *modify a file/directory only when your desired state doesn't match*.

You have two options:

- write a patch for the tools
- write a wrapper, as larsks suggested in the comments above

Depending on the size of your filesystem / directory structure that may increases the runtime of your cron job quite dramatically, though.